# Finding a text node in xml using xpath problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri, title

I'm using rails and the Nokogiri parser. My xml is as below and I'm trying to get the 'Biology: 08:00' text into my view.

```
 <rss version="2.0">
      <channel>
        <item>
          <title>Biology: 08:00</title>
          <description>Start time of Biology</description>
          <pubDate>Tue, 13 Oct 2009 UT</pubDate>
        </item>
       </channel>
    </rss>
```

I can find the node with the text 'biology' using the code below

@content = doc.xpath('//title[contains(text(),"Biology")]')

When I move it into my view it strangely ends up as the title of my .html.erb page. I can't seem to get it into the body with

```
<body>
<%=@content%>
</body>
```

anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the whole node, and the node is a `<title>` tag.

you want:

```
@content = doc.xpath('//title[contains(text(),"Biology")]/text()')
```

to get the text content of the node